# Is this amplifier correctly made?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, simulation, design, homework

This is a returning question from a while back ([Design a power amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639904/design-a-power-amplifier))
So, in general thanks to help from this site I managed to get to this point and I am very thankful, but now I have to examine my simulations and as a novice I can't really say if my simulations are plausible for a working amplifier!
In general I got to have 4 types of simulations: ac-sweep, dc-sweep, stability(I don't know at all what this could mean) and amplification.
Below I will be attaching the documentation I have on my amplifier. Is it remotely correct? Why is my amplification truncated on the negative side? Why is the dc-sweep simulation so scuffed at output? What does a stability simulation mean? In need I can link my entire project! Thanks in advance to all!
[image: The values when the simulation is done][image]
[image]

[image: ac-sweep]
[image: amplification]
[image: dc-sweep]

Comment: I would expect to see something like 18 to 20 volts p-p without clipping.

Comment: 1.5A through a BC846B transistor (a 100mA max device) is not reasonable. Nor is 1.6A quiescent current needed to drive a 133 ohm load.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you! It was an oversight from me! I fixed it right away and it look much better!

Comment: It is correctly designed if it fills the specs you are given. Does it fill the specs? It also needs to fill the specs of each component, like no 2A through a 100mA transistor, or allowing 10W dissipation in a 0.1W resistor, etc.

Comment: There is a problem with the diodes D9,D10,D11,D12. They all have a forward voltage significantly larger than the 0.7 V it should be and the forward currents are a few nA. It's almost as though they are connected reverse biased even though they are shown as being connected correctly forward biased.

Comment: ..... as a result, the current sources are sourcing way too much current and overdriving the output transistors.